# Have conditional fields in entityform

Tags: 7, forms, entities

So it's my first time using [entityform](https://drupal.org/project/entityform) module which is awesome to create an order form.

Within my form, I have an "Entity Reference" field which prepoppulating as checkboxes from my "Node: Products".

in my order form now I have my node:title to choose from, what I want is that another field appear IF the user select one.

mainly I want the user to be able to select/check the product name then provide the amount he is ordering with another textfield or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried [conditional fields](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module which is in dev version to make it works!

> Conditional fields module, define dependencies between fields based on their states and values.